# PHP: file to array check and replace

Tags: php, filter

I have this code that should first process the whole file of words into an array then check the string passed for any of those words in the file. if match, then replace with *.

the file is something like:

```
wordalex
wordjordan
wordjohn
....
```

unfortunately the sentence I passed is not filtered in the fashion I expect. Actually nothing happens to it at all. Could you please look at the code given and help.

```
$comment = "the wordalex if this doesn't get caught!";
$filterWords = file('badwords.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
//print_r($filterWords);
$textToPrint = filterwords($comment,$filterWords );
echo $textToPrint;

function filterwords($text, $filterArray){
    $filterCount = sizeof($filterWords);
    for($i=0; $i<$filterCount; $i++){
        $text = preg_replace('/\b'.$filterWords[$i].'\b/ie',"str_repeat('*',strlen('$0'))",$text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

so there are bard words actually in the original sentence but removed for the posting purpose.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your function definition, you call the word list `$filterArray`.

```
function filterwords($text, $filterArray){
```

But throughout your function, you call it `$filterWords`.

Either rename it to `$filterWords` in the definition or rename each occurrence to `$filterArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Build `$filterWords` while ignoring empty lines. You actually need both `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`

```
$filterWords = file('badwords.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Build replacement arrays:

```
$replacements = array();
$patterns = array();

foreach ($filterWords as $word) {
    // ignore empty words, just in case
    if (empty($word)) continue;        

    $replacements[] = str_repeat('*', strlen($word));
    $patterns[] = "/\b$word\b/i";
}
```

And then do `preg_replace()`:

```
$textToPrint = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $comment);
```

This would yield `Hello ******** NOTwordjohn` from `Hello wordJoHN NOTwordjohn`.

Comment: Thanks and this does work...but it doesn't do regular expressions matching...so if I write the world class it becomes cl***. I want it to ignore those words when they are part of a whole word and not on their own :)

Comment: Edited with `preg_replace()` to do only word matching.

Comment: again it is the same error with preg. Any way this could be sorted uzyn? Really appreciate the effort 
<br><br> Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 2

Comment: I actually tried running the code without any errors. Is your `$filterWords` really an array of words?

Comment: I believe there are blank words in your `$filterWords`. Just edited the code to ignore empty words. Please try.

Comment: Might `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` also accomplish that?

Comment: @Wiseguy Just gave that a try. Thanks. It actually requires both `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` to work. Editing my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to do a `var_dump()` on `$filterWords`, `$replacements` and `$patterns` to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Does your word list happen to contain any of the regex metacharacters such as `^`, `.`, etc? If yes you'll have to escape it with `\`.

Comment: Sounds like the word may start with a quantifier, such as in `+as+y` ("tasty", lol). It would probably be easiest to enclose the word with `\Q` and `\E` so everything will be taken literally: `/\b\Q$word\E\b/i`. However, if this is the problem, the pattern won't match anyway because `+` is not a word character (so it won't match the `\b`). Might have to add options of `(\b|\s|^)` or something instead of just `\b`, and a similar thing for the `\b` on the end.

Comment: Ah no the words don't have any of those characters Uzyn. oh and that Wiseguy for clarification :)